# Is there a way to attach a Mouse Listener to *everything* in SWT/Jface? Eclipse 3.4

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on a Sidebar Widget, which can handle lots of drag & drop inputs. Unfortunately, there seems no way to determine whether the user uses the left or right mouse button for his drag operation (since I only define the drop Listeners and don't have access to the Drag listeners...).

My idea of a workaround was to attach a Filter to the display like this:

```
Display.getDefault().addFilter(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
public void handleEvent(Event paramEvent) {
//do stuff
});
```

Unfortunately, this only listenes to some parts of the workbench and doesn't get triggered for others - editors for instance.
Is there any other way to catch **all** the Mouse Down events in the workbench?

Comment: Eclipse 3.4 is very old.

Comment: IBM Notes uses eclipse 3.4 as platform. So it may be impossible to update.

Comment: By the way: Why do you need the DragStart? Would a DregEnter not be sufficent?

Comment: Jup. Notes is using 3.4, so I can't move to anything sensible. DragEnter doesn't provide you mouse key information...

Comment: Your code will catch all events in the workbench, which are drawn by SWT. But many parts of Notes are still drawn by the old Notes 7.x C++ Client. All clicks in this parts will not generate Events in your SWT Display.